# How to get my Django template to recognize a model method?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

In my django template `<p>This user is unsubscribed {{sub.is_unsubscribed}}</p>` always displays "This user is unsubcribed False" even when it should show True based on the following models.py

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

class Subscriber(models.Model):
    email = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def is_unsubscribed(self):
        try:
            get_object_or_404(MasterUnsubscriber, unsubcriber_email=self.email)
            return True
        except:
            return False


    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

class MasterUnsubscriber(models.Model):
    unsubscriber_email= models.CharField(max_length=12)
```

And for structural reasons of my app, I do not want to move the unsubscribe to the `Subscriber` model as a boolean. How can this be resolved while keeping same model formats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_object_or_404` will raise an error if there is no element at all, or when there are multiple such elements, since the underlying implementation is to use `.get(..)`. You can make use of `.exists()` instead:

```
class Subscriber(models.Model):
    # …

    def is_unsubscribed(self):
        return MasterUnsubscriber.objects.filter(unsubscriber_email=self.mail).exists()
```

That being said, I would advice to make use a [**`ForeignKey`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey) to the subscriber, not by matching the email address. This will be inefficient, since search on a non-indexed column is slow, and furthermore if the user later changes their email, then the all of a sudden, these can be subscribed again. Django also has convenient ways to filter or make aggregates on related objects, so you get more out of the Django ORM.